# Universal deep link IOS with redirects

Tags: ios, swift, redirect, deep-linking

Is there way to open redirected universal deep link url to app?
If app isnt installed it'll go to appstore, its okay, but if app already installed, im still going to appstore instead an app, how to fix it?

I need to open redirected url from deeplink universal

Comment: https://medium.com/wolox/ios-deep-linking-url-scheme-vs-universal-links-50abd3802f97

Answer (score 0):

Here is a web article that could assist you:
https://abhimuralidharan.medium.com/universal-links-in-ios-79c4ee038272
The problem you're experiencing may be associated with the applink information added in your Xcode Associated Domain. Please ensure there are no spelling mistakes, and confirm that your app delegate appropriately manages universal links. Implement the application(_:continue:restorationHandler:) method to handle incoming links.